# Jest React Native Unable to find an element with testID:

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm using Jest to test my React Native app but im having a lots of trouble.
One of them is this error: `Unable to find an element with testID: loginButton`

This is my JSX code:

```
<Button
 testID="loginButton"
 onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
 Join for free
</Button>
```

and my test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from '../screens/Login';
import {fireEvent, render} from '@testing-library/react-native';

    describe('Login screen', () => {
      it('should go to dashboard', () => {
        const navigation = {navigate: () => {}};
        jest.spyOn(navigation, 'navigate');
    
        const page = render(<Login navigation={navigation} />);
        const loginButton = page.getByTestId('loginButton');
    
        fireEvent.press(loginButton);
    
        expect(navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Home');
      });
    });
```

EDIT: If i do `const loginButton = page.queryAllByTestId('loginButton');` the test passes.

What am i doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to mention that im using NativeBase and my app was wrapped in a `<NativeBaseProvider>`.
To fix the above issue, you can simply pass initialWindowMetrics to NativeBaseProvider in your tests.

```
const inset = {
  frame: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 },
  insets: { top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 },
};

<NativeBaseProvider initialWindowMetrics={inset}>
  {children}
</NativeBaseProvider>;
```